# Update composer skeleton project

Tags: php, composer-php

Composer allows to create a project basing on the specified package:

```
composer create-project vendor/project-name
```

Is it possible to update this project in the future like `composer update-project` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. `update-project` does not exist.

However, from the docs on [`create-project`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#create-project):

> This is the equivalent of doing a git clone/svn checkout followed by a "composer install" of the vendors.

As such, it might be possible to `git pull` or `svn up` the *project* source. Most projects offer their own project update tools for newer versions of the project.